# Positioning in Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf

Good day all, I am trying to remove

```
\node (ground1) at (0,-5)  [ground, anchor=north] {};
```

and put the

```
\draw plot[domain=0:3*pi/.9,smooth] (\x,{sin(0.9*\x r)});
```

Also is their anyway I can control the number of loop on the sine wave.
Thanks.

Kindly see MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % to add figure environment that comes with caption
\usepackage{caption} %if you don't want to float your figure for using \captionof
\usepackage{tikz}           
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings,circuits}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,outer sep=0pt,thick}]
 \tikzstyle{spring}=[thick,decorate,decoration={zigzag,pre length=0.3cm,post length=0.3cm,segment length=6}]
 \tikzstyle{dampener}=[thick,decoration={markings, mark connection node=dmp,mark=at position 0.5 with {
 \node (dmp) [thick,inner sep=0pt,transform shape,rotate=-90,minimum width=15pt,minimum height=3pt,draw=none] {};
 \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north east)+(2pt,0)$) -- (dmp.south east) -- (dmp.south west) -- ($(dmp.north west)+(2pt,0)$); \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north)+(0,-5pt)$) -- ($(dmp.north)+(0,5pt)$);}}, decorate]
 \tikzstyle{ground}=[fill,pattern=north east lines,draw=none,minimum width=4cm,minimum height=0.3cm]
 \begin{scope}
 \node at (0,0) [draw,rectangle, minimum width=2cm,minimum height=1cm,fill=gray,anchor=south,,transform shape](m1) {$Engine\: mass$};
 \draw [very thick, -latex](m1.east) -- +(1,0)--+(1,1)node[draw=none,midway,right=0.4cm] {y};
 \node at (0,-2) [rectangle, minimum width=4cm,minimum height=1cm,fill=gray,anchor=north,,transform shape](m2) {$Body\: mass$};
 \draw [very thick, -latex](m2.east) -- +(1,0)--+(1,1)node[draw=none,midway,right=0.4cm] {x};
 \draw [spring] (-0.5,-2) -- (-0.5,0) node[draw=none,midway,left=0.3cm] {$3{k}{_R}$};
 \draw [dampener,label=D1,] (0.5,-2) -- (0.5,0)node[draw=none,midway,right=0.4cm] {$3{C}{_R}$};

 \node (ground1) at (0,-5)  [ground, anchor=north] {};
 \draw plot[domain=0:3*pi/.9,smooth] (\x,{sin(0.9*\x r)});
 \draw [spring] (-0.5,-5) -- (-0.5,-3)node[draw=none,midway,left=0.3cm] {$2{k}{_s}{_f}+2{k}{_s}{_r}$};
 \draw [dampener] (0.5,-5) -- (0.5,-3)node[draw=none,midway,right=0.4cm] {$2{C}{_s}{_f}+2{C}{_s}{_r}$};

 \end{scope}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \caption{2-parameter rubber mount}\label{fig:2-parameter rubber mount}
 \end{figure}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really understand your question. If you want to remove that node, why don't you just remove it? And what do you want to do with the plot?

Comment: I want to put the plot where the node is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can draw what you want with a decoration:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[decoration={snake,segment length=4mm,amplitude=2mm},decorate,fill=white] (-2,0) --
       (2,0);
    \draw[decoration={snake,segment length=3mm,amplitude=2mm},decorate,fill=white] (-2,-1) --
       (2,-1);
    \draw[decoration={snake,segment length=2mm,amplitude=2mm},decorate,fill=white] (-2,-2) --
       (2,-2);
    \draw[decoration={snake,segment length=1mm,amplitude=2mm},decorate,fill=white] (-2,-3) --
       (2,-3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can adjust `amplitude` and `segment length` to get the desired number of waves.

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % to add figure environment that comes with caption
\usepackage{caption} %if you don't want to float your figure for using \captionof
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings,circuits}

\tikzset{
   mysnake/.style={decoration={snake,segment length=4mm,amplitude=2mm},decorate
     },
   spring/.style = {thick,decorate,decoration={zigzag,pre length=0.3cm,post length=0.3cm,
          segment length=6}},
   dampener/.style = {thick,decoration={markings, mark connection node=dmp,mark=at
          position 0.5 with {\node (dmp) [thick,inner sep=0pt,transform shape,rotate=-90,
          minimum width=15pt,minimum height=3pt,draw=none] {};
          \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north east)+(2pt,0)$) -- (dmp.south east) -- (dmp.south west)
          -- ($(dmp.north west)+(2pt,0)$); \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north)+(0,-5pt)$) --
           ($(dmp.north)+(0,5pt)$);}}, decorate},
   ground/.style ={fill,pattern=north east lines,draw=none,minimum width=4cm,minimum
            height=0.3cm}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,outer sep=0pt,thick}]
 \begin{scope}
 \node at (0,0) [draw,rectangle, minimum width=2cm,minimum height=1cm,fill=gray,anchor=south,,transform shape](m1) {$Engine\: mass$};
 \draw [very thick, -latex](m1.east) -- +(1,0)--+(1,1)node[draw=none,midway,right=0.4cm] {y};
 \node at (0,-2) [rectangle, minimum width=4cm,minimum height=1cm,fill=gray,anchor=north,,transform shape](m2) {$Body\: mass$};
 \draw [very thick, -latex](m2.east) -- +(1,0)--+(1,1)node[draw=none,midway,right=0.4cm] {x};
 \draw [spring] (-0.5,-2) -- (-0.5,0) node[draw=none,midway,left=0.3cm] {$3{k}{_R}$};
 \draw [dampener,label=D1,] (0.5,-2) -- (0.5,0)node[draw=none,midway,right=0.4cm] {$3{C}{_R}$};

  \draw [spring] (-0.5,-5) -- (-0.5,-3)node[draw=none,midway,left=0.3cm] {$2{k}{_s}{_f}+2{k}{_s}{_r}$};
 \draw [dampener] (0.5,-5) -- (0.5,-3)node[draw=none,midway,right=0.4cm] {$2{C}{_s}{_f}+2{C}{_s}{_r}$};
 %\node (ground1) at (0,-5)  [ground, anchor=north] {};
 %\draw plot[domain=0:3*pi/.9,smooth] (\x,{sin(0.9*\x r)});
 \fill[white]decorate[mysnake]{(-2,-4.8) -- (2,-4.8)} --(2,-5.1) -- (-2,-5.1) -- (-2,-4.8) --cycle;
\draw[mysnake] (-2,-4.8) -- (2,-4.8);
 \end{scope}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \caption{2-parameter rubber mount}\label{fig:2-parameter rubber mount}
 \end{figure}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

I have defined a new style `mysnake` for the purpose and converted all `\tikzstyle`s in to `\tikzset`s since the former is obsolete.

Comment: Thanks Harish Kumar. Really grateful. But is their anyway the two could merge together instead of the snake to be overlapping with the upper part? Thanks once again.

Comment: @IsmailLadeleLadipo Please see the edit.

Comment: (+1) for understanding the question ;).

Comment: I am not sure if this is the right thing to do or not. I am trying to add this two block shapes together but with little or no progree.

Comment: @IsmailLadeleLadipo What do you mean? I didn't follow. Does this answer not solve your problem?